Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow - Langchain core
I am able to execute the following code successfully in Jupyter Notebook and able to produce output.
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableParallel, RunnablePassthrough, RunnableLambda
from tqdm import tqdm
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from openai import AzureOpenAI
from langchain_elasticsearch import ElasticsearchRetriever
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain_openai.chat_models.azure import AzureChatOpenAI

es_url = "https://elastic:xx@awsxx:9200"
es_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=[es_url])
index_name = "multi_xv1"
openai_azure_endpoint = "https://xxx.openai.azure.com/"
openai_api_version = "2023-07-01-preview"
openai_api_key = "xxx"

client = AzureOpenAI(api_key = openai_api_key,  api_version = openai_api_version, azure_endpoint =openai_azure_endpoint)


def hybrid_query(search_query) :
    vector  = client.embeddings.create(input=search_query , model="text-embedding-ada-002")
    vector = vector.data[0].embedding
    return {
        "query": {
            "match": {
                "page_content": search_query,
            },
        },
        "knn": {
            "field": "Page_Embeddings",
            "query_vector": vector,
            "k": 5,
            "num_candidates": 10,
        },
        "rank": {"rrf": {}},
        "_source": [
            "page_content"
          ],
    }


hybrid_retriever = ElasticsearchRetriever.from_es_params(
    index_name=index_name,
    body_func=hybrid_query,
    content_field="page_content",
    url=es_url,
)

ret = {}
ret[0] = hybrid_retriever

def format_docs(docs):
    pages = []
    for doc in docs:
        pages.append(doc.page_content)
    return pages
    
prompt_template = """
Provide an detailed summary of parts answering the question '{topic}' in the study.
Write as a medical writer. Do not provide title of the study in the response. 
If information is not present in the text output "Information not available"
Texts:
'{context}'

Provide an detailed summary of parts answering the question '{topic}' in the study.
Write as a medical writer. Do not provide title of the study in the response. 
If information is not present in the text output "Information not available"
"""
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(prompt_template)
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(azure_deployment="gpt-4-32k",openai_api_version="2023-03-15-preview",azure_endpoint = "https://xxx.openai.azure.com/",openai_api_key = "xxx", temperature = 0)

chain = ({"context": ret[0]|format_docs, "topic": RunnablePassthrough()}
        | prompt
        | llm
        | StrOutputParser())
        
print (chain.invoke("What is the efficacy or statistics on efficacy information in this study?"))

But the code is failing with the following error in linux environment. I verified all the langchain packages. Versions are same.
Error:
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007fbdcc4c1740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain_core/load/serializable.py", line 114 in <listcomp>
  ...
Aborted (core dumped)

Any inputs appreciated. Thanks.
Any

First sentence in the text says, "I am able to execute the following code successfully in Jupyter Notebook and .." and then the next sentence says, "But the code is failing with the following error in linux environment." You seem to have left out some details needed to make it clear to us what you are comparing here. So is Jupyter running in the context of Linux, too, or a different system altogether? In regards to, "But the code is failing with the following error in linux environment." You mean when the code in the provided code block us run as a script using Python on Linux command line?
